# How should a docker container obtain a reference/path to a file which exists outside of the docker container

Tags: docker, ssl

I have a service running in a docker container which needs to load an SSL certificate that is generated by cerbot.

Certbot always puts the files in a directory like `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem`.

As a temporary solution I have copied the cert files into my docker container and referenced those local (to docker) files. However, as soon as the certificate needs renewing I would have to manually copy those files again, which is not ideal.

How can I provide my docker container with that file path so that come renewal, the certificates will still be valid without requiring manual intervention?

Comment: You can just mount a file or directory into the container namespace. But usually applications which read certificates have to be restared / reloaded anyway in order to use the new one.

Comment: Thanks @HaukeLaging I'll look into mounting.